# MissingMethodException in groovy for a static class

Tags: java, groovy

I get a `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException` in a class which is importing a static class.

Here's the implementation.

```
import Corpus
class InRe {
    Corpus corpus
       corpus.posts().each{
       }
}

class L {
  public static class Corpus{
     public posts(){
     }
  }
}
```

And when I run my main class, it throws a

> Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No
> signature of method:
>
> edu.msu.mi.forum.replies.InferReplies$_signatureExtractionByFrequentClosing_closure10.doCall() is applicable for argument types:
>
> (edu.msu.mi.forum.webmd.WebMdConversation) values:
> [edu.msu.mi.forum.webmd.WebMdConversation@fb309] Possible solutions:
> doCall(edu.msu.mi.forum.model.Post), findAll(), findAll(),
> isCase(java.lang.Object), isCase(java.lang.Object)

So my question is if I call a method from a static inner class, is that out of scope ?

Comment: You need to import `L.Corpus`.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to get to the Corpus class.

The Corpus class is a static class inside L class.

The following code:

```
class InRe {
   Corpus corpus
   corpus.posts().each{
   } 
}
```

should be changed to:

```
class InRe {
   L.Corpus corpus = new L.Corpus()
   corpus.posts().each{
   } 
}
```

The access to the **Corpus** is not direct so you can reach to it using the **L.Corpus**
The import should be related to the class position, means that the import should be

```
import L
```

> **In general:** Static nested classes are accessed using the enclosing class name.

Supporting the written above you can follow the [java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).